# subset function in R

Tags: r

'data' is a large dataset. I want to use subset-function to only get some user's in 'data'.

```
dim(subset(data, data$user == c(1,2)))
```

I get 110 12.

```
dim(subset(data, data$user==1))
```

I get 9 12 and for

```
dim(subset(data, data$user==2))
```

I get 214 12.

This is strange because 9+214 is not equal 110 so it seems like I can't use the subset-function to get more than one user. How can that be?

Comment: You can use `%in%` for multiple elements ie. `subset(data, user %in% 1:2)` Another way would be `subset(data, user==1 | user==2)`  Also, inside the `subset`, you don't have to use `data$`.

Comment: For these two it works but when I do it for more it say "longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length"

Comment: Usually, it should work with `%in%`.  But, I can't comment without a reproducible example.

Comment: If you have more than one value to compare against just use `%in%` and get over with. I can't think of any case it won't work. The warning message you are getting is for using `==` in inappropriate manner.

Comment: Thanks for the response. It works fine but how can I do it if I want entries in a vector like u[1], u[2],.., u[10] for example. What should I do then ? I can't use %in% u[1]:u[10] because it would simply take all from u[1] to u[10] but I only want u[1], u[2],..., u[10].